# How to get a range of data in mongodb for a substring of field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am having a field as build and another as data in my MongoDB. my build field is as b3312, b3313, b3313... I want to fetch data for a range of builds. can we add regex with it and gt in find query? or is there any other solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
let build_ids = ["b3312","b3313","b3314"];
db.collectionName.find({build: {$in: build_ids}})
```

Comment: Thanks. This helps

Answer (score 1):

you can use

**$lte**

> selects the documents where the value of the field is less than or
> equal to (i.e. <=) the specified value.

**$gte**

> selects the documents where the value of the field is greater than or
> equal to (i.e. >=) a specified value

```
db.collectionName.find( { build : { $gte: "b3312", $lte :  "b3314"} } )
```

result:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60118271fec3d8db92a39872"),
    "build" : "b3312"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60118279fec3d8db92a3987e"),
    "build" : "b3313"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6011827ffec3d8db92a3988b"),
    "build" : "b3314"
}
```

Comment: The string is bigger as **build1-dev-b3312** and so on. I am not sure if `$gte` and `$lte` would work with a string data.
I need to do a regex to fetch the build number "3312" and then use `$gte` and `$lte` on that. Kindly share your thoughts.